# Can't import three.meshline, "Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use three.meshline for my React project, but I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (THREE.MeshLine.js:11:1)
    at Object../node_modules/three.meshline/src/THREE.MeshLine.js (THREE.MeshLine.js:714:1)
    at Object.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)...
```

I installed it via npm and imported it as described on the docs:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { MeshLine } from "three.meshline";
```

Just adding the import line gave me the error. It seems to be occurring in the THREE.MeshLine.js file at the line they use THREE.BufferGeometry:

```
;(function() {
  'use strict'

  var root = this

  var has_require = typeof require !== 'undefined'

  var THREE = root.THREE || (has_require && require('three'))
  if (!THREE) throw new Error('MeshLine requires three.js')

  class MeshLine extends THREE.BufferGeometry {
    constructor()
    {...
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same here, I added a breakpoint in the debug tool and found out the THREE is a string, and the `'string'.BufferGeometry` turned out undefined in this case. This is so far I got, the issue still not resolved yet.

Comment: Same problem. Receive a strange error.

Comment: THREE.MeshLine.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (THREE.MeshLine.js:11:1)
    at ./node_modules/three.meshline/src/THREE.MeshLine.js (THREE.MeshLine.js:714:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/index.js (App.js:7:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1